# Understanding of INSTR(pm.BUSINESS,',') >0

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a large query which I am not able to understand. I have followed [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564) to understand the syntax of `INSTR` but no luck.

Is it saying if the column pm.BUSINESS has a value with commas (,) then return 'Global' ?

Here is some part of the query

```
SELECT CASE WHEN INSTR(pm.BUSINESS,',') > 0 
                  THEN 'Global' 
            ELSE pm.BUSINESS END "BUSINESS LINE",
                  pm.PUB_TYPE "PUB_TYPE",
                  pm.PUB_TITLE "PUB_TITLE",
                  a.HITS "TOTAL VIEWS",
                  a.INT "EMP_VIEWS",
                  a.EXT "CL_VIEWS",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm) solely about `INSTR`. It says:

> The INSTR functions search string for substring. The function returns an integer indicating the position of the character in string that is the first character of this occurrence.

So as you assumed, if `pm.BUSINESS` contains any comma, your query returns `'Global'`. If not, it returns the value of `pm.BUSINESS`.